# c# Get the cell text value if DataError is triggered

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I populate it dynamically from my database via the following code

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colID.HeaderText = "id";
colID.DataPropertyName = "id";
colID.ReadOnly = true;
colID.Visible = false;
dtgvLoadEx.Columns.Add(colID);

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colLoadExpiryDate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
//CalendarColumn colLoadExpiryDate = new CalendarColumn();
colLoadExpiryDate.HeaderText = "LoadExpiryDate(mm/dd/yy)";
colLoadExpiryDate.Width = 158;
colLoadExpiryDate.DataPropertyName = "LoadExpiryDate";
colLoadExpiryDate.ReadOnly = false;
colLoadExpiryDate.MaxInputLength = 10;
dtgvLoadEx.Columns.Add(colLoadExpiryDate);

dtgvLoadEx.DataSource = data(); //Return data table from my Database
```

As you can see I have a `Date` column. When I attempt to edit a cell of that column and type an invalid format, the `DataError` event will triggered.

Now I just want to get the error text from

```
private void dtgvLoadEx_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {

}
```

or any other process in order to get the error text.

Comment: How to you raise an error when invalid text is entered?

Comment: for example I insert in to that column this "2023123" it will trigger the _DataError Event. Now i Just want to get that "2023123"

Comment: What sort of exception is in e.Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys I Already Solved the Problem. Here I'm gonna share it

```
 private void dtgvLoadEx_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = dtgvLoadEx.EditingControl.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the event argument as follows

```
string errorText;
private void dataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    // This will return the last text entry that was not erroneous.
    string cellValue = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    // This will get the text indicating the error condition.
    errorText = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText;
}
```

*Edit. Having read your comment below, if the first of the above is not returning the erroneous striing value, then it might not be possible. Try using `ErrorText` instead.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: I try this but it return the previous value of the datagridview. It does not return the error value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a custom validation using CellValidating event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender,
DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(e.FormattedValue))
    {
         string s = e.FormattedValue;
         e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```